# Не стрелять при нажатии на GUI. Unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, gui

Я делаю мобильный топ-даун шутер на андроид. И там игрок стреляет по клику мыши на экран.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
    if (weaponType == "bullet" && bulletLauncher != null && energy > 1)
    {
        Energy--;
        bulletLauncher.Launch(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
    }
{
```

Но кроме того он стреляет при нажатии на элементы интерфейса (Джойстик).
 Как этого избежать? Я использую cnControls.

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку, какой клавишей вы нажимаете на gui и какой клавишей стреляете?) А теперь думаем... можно еще зайти в edit-project settings-input и посмотреть на axis вкладку fire1. Не используйте стрельбу мышкой fire1, используйте кнопку на gui

Comment: Или можно положить под все UI - панель, на весь экран, которая будет перехватывать нажатия

Comment: @Xumera_hZ, 1) все равно нужна стрельба мышкой, что бы ходить и стрелять одновременно. 2) Возможно я туповат, но я не улавливаю здесь связи "какой клавишей вы нажимаете на gui и какой клавишей стреляете?)" хз вообще какой клавишей я нажимаю на gui, это джойстик, он работает через onDrag.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ,  игрок стреляет по нажатию на любое место экрана в точку касания. Нужно сделать, что бы не стреляло при нажатии на джойстик

Comment: @Sithell Unity соотносит нажатие левой клавиши с 1 тачем, второй кнопки с 2 тачем и т.д. Можно сделать и текущей реализацией, надо при нажатии fire1, проверку сделать, что он не находится в области джойстика.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ, а, понял. Я это уже сделал, игнорирую нажатия в прямоугольнике с джойстиком, но мне казалось, что это костыль. Нет ли другого способа?

Comment: @Sithell а по другому никак, canvas UI по такому же принципу работает, только там дополнительно кидают graphics.raycast( проверка наложения) Просто представь себе механизм есть экран и точка на экране, как определить, что точка в определенной области экрана?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самым правильным решением в данной ситуации будет поместить весь ваш UI, при нажатии на который вы не хотите инициировать выстрел на отдельный физический слой, скажем UI. Далее в вашем коде стрельбы делать [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)
по выбранному вами слою (в данном примере это будет слой UI), если в результате Raycast получит hit по какому-либо объекту - это будет означать, что пользователь нажал на какую-то кнопку, и выстрел производить не нужно. Raycast нужно выпусть из точки, где было произведено нажатие ([позиция мыши](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html)) в положительном направлении по оси Z. Если решение не будет работать в таком виде, то можно получить позицию мыши в Vector3 и изменить ее Z координату, например на -5, чтобы сам Raycast происходил "из-за экрана".

Данное решение используется часто и не является "костыльным", так как сама по себе операция Raycast не является ресурсоемкой.

Comment: судя по записям из [unity3d.com](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-best-practices) про Raycasts - "This however, is **an expensive** operation; its performance is highly influenced by the ray’s length and type of colliders on the scene."..... так что не думаю, что утверждение `операция Raycast не является ресурсоемкой` является верным

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, данное замечание в документации, скорее всего, справедливо потому, что в принципе любое взаимодействие с физикой в unity является ресурсоемким, так как по умолчанию для этого используется Box2D, который не является частью unity и используется ими как черный ящик. Однако стоит также заметить, что среди всех возможностей unity, связанных с физикой Raycast является самой дешевой операцией. В данном случае, если использовать Raycast только по объектам интерфейса, можно, к тому же, минимизировать  длину и маску самого луча, сделав операцию экономичней.

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class test : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler {
int index = 0;
int clickIndex = 0;
bool canShoot = true;

void Shoot() {
    index++;
    Debug.Log("shoot index: " + index);
}

public void ButtonClick() {
    clickIndex++;
    Debug.Log("i'm clicked " + clickIndex + " times");
}

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData) {
        canShoot = false;
        Debug.Log("can shoot:" + canShoot);
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData) {
        canShoot = true;
        Debug.Log("can shoot:" + canShoot);
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canShoot) {
        Shoot();
    }
}
```

}

попробуйте этот код.
ссылка: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html
при наведении мышки будет свичатся canShoot, что не позволит произвести выстрел. в Вашем же случае, наведение равно Click, вы можете заменить Enter на Click:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html

Comment: Стоит заметить, что в вашем решении не получится стрелять на ходу, т.к. при нажатии на джойстик стрельба заблокирована.